# Delete the last added row (added by button btn1) on click of button btn2

Tags: android

In the below code Button `btn1` is adding a row (it is working fine). How to delete the last added row after clicking button `btn2`?

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TableRow row1 = new TableRow(create_form.this);
        TextView txt1 = new TextView(create_form.this);
        EditText edttxt1 = new EditText(create_form.this);
        txt1.setText("Topic");
        TableRow row2 = new TableRow(create_form.this);
        TextView txt2 = new TextView(create_form.this);
        EditText edttxt2 = new EditText(create_form.this);
        txt2.setText("Employee Name");
        row1.addView(txt1);
        row1.addView(edttxt1);
        row2.addView(txt2);
        row2.addView(edttxt2);
        t1.addView(row1);
        t1.addView(row2);
    }
});

btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override public void onClick(View v) {
        // What code to add here to delete the last added row?
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this. This code might help you.

```
  final TableRow tempTrRow1 = (TableRow)  tlRow.getChildAt(tblMain.getChildCount()-1);
        tblMain.removeView(tempTrRow1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TableRow lastRow = (TableRow)t1.getChildAt(t1.getChildCount() - 1);
t1.removeView(lastRow);
```

Comment: you 'd rather explain why your code will solve the op question.